# WSGIRequest is not callable 'blockchain project'

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a blockchain project, but I had a problem that I could not solve myself, and here I share all the details of the project.

## Mining a new block

````py
def mine_block(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        previous_block = blockchain.get_last_block()
        previous_nonce = previous_block['nonce']
        nonce = blockchain.proof_of_work(previous_nonce)
        previous_hash = blockchain.hash(previous_block)
        blockchain.add_transaction(sender = root_node, receiver = node_address, amount = 1.15, time=str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        block = blockchain.create_block(nonce, previous_hash)
        response = render(request({'message': 'Congratulations, you just mined a block!',
                    'index': block['index'],
                    'timestamp': block['timestamp'],
                    'nonce': block['nonce'],
                    'previous_hash': block['previous_hash'],
                    'transactions': block['transactions']}))
    return render(JsonResponse(response))
‍```
# Getting the full Blockchain
‍‍‍‍‍```
def get_chain(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        response = render(request({'chain': blockchain.chain,
                    'length': len(blockchain.chain)}))
    return render(request,JsonResponse(response))
````

## Checking if the Blockchain is valid

```
def is_valid(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        is_valid = blockchain.is_chain_valid(blockchain.chain)
        if is_valid:
            response = render(request({'message': 'All good. The Blockchain is valid.'}))
        else:
            response = render(request({'message': 'Houston, we have a problem. The Blockchain is not valid.'}))
    return render(request,JsonResponse(response))
```

## Adding a new transaction to the Blockchain

```
@csrf_exempt
def add_transaction(request): #New
    if request.method == 'POST':
        received_json = json.loads(request.body)
        transaction_keys = ['sender', 'receiver', 'amount','time']
        if not all(key in received_json for key in transaction_keys):
            return 'Some elements of the transaction are missing', HttpResponse(request(status=400))
        index = blockchain.add_transaction(received_json['sender'], received_json['receiver'], received_json['amount'],received_json['time'])
        response = render(request({'message': f'This transaction will be added to Block {index}'}))
    return render(request,JsonResponse(response))
```

## Connecting new nodes

```
@csrf_exempt
def connect_node(request): #New
    if request.method == 'POST':
        received_json = json.loads(request.body)
        nodes = received_json.get('nodes')
        if nodes is None:
            return "No node", HttpResponse(request(status=400))
        for node in nodes:
            blockchain.add_node(node)
        response = render(request({'message': 'All the nodes are now connected. The Sudocoin Blockchain now contains the following nodes:',
                    'total_nodes': list(blockchain.nodes)}))
    return render(request,JsonResponse(response))
```

## Replacing the chain by the longest chain if needed

```
def replace_chain(request): #New
    if request.method == 'GET':
  is_chain_replaced = blockchain.replace_chain()
        if is_chain_replaced:
            response = render(request({'message': 'The nodes had different chains so the chain was replaced by the longest one.',
                        'new_chain': blockchain.chain}))
        else:
            response = render(request({'message': 'All good. The chain is the largest one.',
                        'actual_chain': blockchain.chain}))
    return render(request,JsonResponse(response))
```

this is my code

```
TypeError: 'WSGIRequest' object is not callable
```

this is error

```
Django version==4
python==3.8
```

and versions of Django and Python
Thanks for telling me the solution

Comment: `request(...)` in your `render`s is the reason you're getting this error. You are trying to call an object that is not supposed to be called like that in views.  Have you previously worked with django?

Comment: oh No, I have not worked with Django before. This is almost my first project

Comment: do you know how work it ?

Comment: Read the tutorial then: [part one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/). Find the functions/objects you don't understand in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/). 
Learn what callable objects are, etc. SO positions itself less as a learning resourse and more as a issue-solving resourse.

Comment: I read this documents and I can't find my answer 

Comment: `response = render(request({...}))` + `return render(JsonResponse(response))` → `data = {...}` + `return JsonResponse(data)`